# Is asp.net vulnerable to object serialization like java server platforms

Tags: java, asp.net, spring, security

Infoq published this very serious vulnerability about all java server platforms :

Remotely Exploitable Java Zero Day Exploits through Deserialization

http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/11/commons-exploit

Is asp.net also concerned: Why not since asp.net do also use serialization ? The guy may not have looked at asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET is not affected by this vulnerability. It is a vulnerability in Apache Common Collections, Groovy and Spring frameworks, which all of them are Java only.
As you can see in the Proof-of-concept code here:
https://github.com/foxglovesec/JavaUnserializeExploits

It only works on Java-based applications and those who use listed vulnerable Serialization/Deserialization functions.

Comment: The guys may have only studied Java that doesn't prove asp.net is not affected ?

Comment: This particular vulnerability is specifically for Java. The way it invokes the Deserialization process to execute a command is Java only.